# efs policy statements identifiers restrictions

Tags: terraform

In EFS Policy (REF: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-efs/blob/master/examples/complete/main.tf) shown below, the pods are able to mount volume and running fine if identifiers is set to *

```
  module "efs" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/efs/aws"

  # File system
  name           = "efs_${var.cluster_name}"
  creation_token = "efs_${var.cluster_name}"
  encrypted      = true
  kms_key_arn    = module.kms.key_arn

  performance_mode                = "maxIO"
  throughput_mode                 = "provisioned"
  provisioned_throughput_in_mibps = 256

  lifecycle_policy = {
    transition_to_ia = "AFTER_30_DAYS"
  }

  # File system policy
  attach_policy                      = true
  bypass_policy_lockout_safety_check = false
  policy_statements = [
    {
      sid     = "${var.cluster_name}"
      actions = ["elasticfilesystem:ClientMount",
                 "elasticfilesystem:ClientRootAccess",
                 "elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite"]
      principals = [
        {
          type        = "AWS"
          identifiers = ["*"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

  # Mount targets / security group
  mount_targets = { for k, v in toset(range(length(["${var.region}a", "${var.region}b", "${var.region}c"]))) :
    element(["${var.region}a", "${var.region}b", "${var.region}c"], k) => { subnet_id = element(data.aws_subnets.private_subnets.ids, k) }
  }
  security_group_description = "${var.cluster_name} EFS security group"
  security_group_vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.default.id
  security_group_rules = {
    vpc = {
      # relying on the defaults provided for EFS/NFS (2049/TCP + ingress)
      description = "NFS ingress from VPC private subnets"
      cidr_blocks = [for s in data.aws_subnet.private_subnet : s.cidr_block]
    }
  }
  

  # Access point(s)
  access_points = {
    # posix_example = {
    #   name = "posix-${var.cluster_name}"
    #   posix_user = {
    #     gid            = 1001
    #     uid            = 1001
    #     secondary_gids = [1002]
    #   }

    #   tags = merge(local.tags)
    # }
    root_dir1 = {
      root_directory = {
        path = "/"
        creation_info = {
          owner_gid   = 1001
          owner_uid   = 1001
          permissions = "755"
        }
      }
    }
  }

  # Backup policy
  enable_backup_policy = false

  # Replication configuration
  create_replication_configuration = false
#   replication_configuration_destination = {
#     region = "eu-west-2"
#   }

  tags = merge(local.tags)
}

module "kms" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/kms/aws"
  version = "~> 1.0"

  aliases               = ["efs/${var.cluster_name}"]
  description           = "EFS customer managed key"
  enable_default_policy = true

  deletion_window_in_days = 7

  tags = merge(local.tags)
}
```

If I set Identifiers to [data.aws_caller_identity.current.arn] , I am getting below error,
Output: Could not start amazon-efs-mount-watchdog, unrecognized init system "aws-efs-csi-dri"
b'mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting 127.0.0.1:/'
Warning: config file does not have fips_mode_enabled item in section mount..

identifier: * seems to be not very restricted. Any suggestions to improve this please?

Comment: It is not clear if you are using the module or you are trying to create your own. The example that you linked has the caller ARN in the identifiers list.

Comment: I am using the module. I used caller arn it didnt work. When I used * ,  it works

Comment: If you are calling that module, please add the entire code block to the question.

Comment: I have updated my question with entire code block